# Accessing inbox messages

Tags: android, sms

I want to access inbox messages. For that, I am writing the following code:

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
String sms = "";
cur.moveToNext();
sms = cur.getString(0);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inboxshowingapp/com.example.inboxshowingapp.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at com.example.inboxshowingapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-07 12:31:37.222: E/AndroidRuntime(687):     ... 11 more
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: shared the logcat..plz chek.

Comment: please indent it properly and i`ve added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to confirm that you have added the permissions in the manifest file.

The following permissions are for messages

```
android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

android.permission.SEND_SMS
```

If so, then you are missing the condition that is if you have more than one contact and what to retrieve the messages of all of them, then you need to mold your code like the following:

```
public List<Sms> getSms() {
    List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
    Sms objSms = new Sms();
    Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();

    Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
    mActivity.startManagingCursor(c);
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

            objSms = new Sms();
            objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
            objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
            } else {
                objSms.setFolderName("sent");
            }

            lstSms.add(objSms);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    // else {
    // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
    // }
    c.close();

    return lstSms;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
  cur.moveToNext();
```

with this:

```
  cur.moveToFirst();
```

And set this permission to your manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);
```

Get all inbox messages:

```
body = new String[c.getCount()];
number = new String[c.getCount()];

if (c.moveToFirst()){
    for (int i=0; i<c.getCount(); i++){
        body[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        number[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
c.close();
```